# JPA + Hibernate Join columns of different type

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have to deal with a MySQL database where there is a "FK" from VARCHAR to Int.

```
Table Foo 
   |-> column "id" Int(11)

Table Bar
   |-> column "fooId" VARCHAR
```

With native sql when I search as:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo f LEFT JOIN Bar b ON f.id = b.fooId ...
```

It works ( I guess MySQL is smart enough )

But when I do the mapping in JPA in my model classes... I get exception that it was excpecting Integer. Any suggestions?

---

EDIT:

```
public class Foo ...

    @Column(name = "ID")
public **Integer** getId() {
    return id;
}

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo")
    public List<Bar> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }



public class Bar

    @Column(name = "foo_id")
public **String** getFooId() {
    return fooId;
}

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="foo_id")
    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
```

Comment: Frankly, the best suggestion is to fix your schema.

Comment: Wish it could be so easy :) . It is not my schema. If it was , it would have correct referencial integrity.